# Laravel mass assignment to model in Update method in abstract class using foreach loops to fill keys with values

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-4

How can I be able to create a generic method of the update() function that belongs to an abstract class. To be precise I want it to be able to generate the array $keys and link with the updated $values dynamically, so that different repositories can use this function from this abstract class.

```
public function update($id, array $data)
{

    $related              = $this->modelClassInstance->find($id);
    $related->name        = $data['name'];
    $related->description = $data['description'];
    $related->started_at  = $data['started_at'];
    $related->ended_at    = $data['ended_at'];

    if($related->save()) {

      $response = MyResponse::error(201, true, 'Event sucessfully updated');

      return $response;
    } 
    else {
      $response = MyResponse::error(200, false, 'Event unsucessfully updated');

      return $response;
    }
}
```

I need something like this

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
   .....
}
```

My keys are the name, description, started_at and ended_at, but that means this function is specific to a model . I want this keys to be generated dynamicaly and to get their new values from the data passed. So that any model with any keys can use it.

Comment: You didn't show us any *array $keys*...

Comment: @mTorres, please check , new edits done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for loop was unneccesary with Laravel methods which are quite reliable, after doing research in various sites. I came up with this simple solution

```
    public function update($id, array $data)
            {
                $related = $this->modelClassInstance->find($id);

                $related->fill($data);

                if($related->save()) 
                {

                    $response = MyResponse::error(201, true, 'Event sucessfully updated');

                    return $response;
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $response = MyResponse::error(200, false, 'Event unsucessfully updated');

                    return $response;
                }
            }
```

This is how the fill() method is implemented in Laravel Eloquent Model, in case you seek similar implementation.

```
public function fill(array $attributes)
    {
        $totallyGuarded = $this->totallyGuarded();

        foreach ($this->fillableFromArray($attributes) as $key => $value)
        {
            $key = $this->removeTableFromKey($key);

            // The developers may choose to place some attributes in the "fillable"
            // array, which means only those attributes may be set through mass
            // assignment to the model, and all others will just be ignored.
            if ($this->isFillable($key))
            {
                $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
            }
            elseif ($totallyGuarded)
            {
                throw new MassAssignmentException($key);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```